# Image loading locally but not on heroku server

Tags: html, node.js, heroku

My code works fine on local deployment, but when uploaded to a heroku server, I get the error message "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" in relation to howling.jpg. Checking the directory with bash shows that the image is on my heroku server to be used but I can't figure out why it won't load it. My canvas in the html file loads without an issue.

[html code of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhAGp.png)

[heroku bash displaying howling.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqZqw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you reference howling.jpg with a relative reference in your code?

If you used an absolute path the directory names may be different and you might not be able to locate your image.

What is your code that is accessing/calling the image location? can you post it here please

Answer (score 0):

fixed by putting into an images folder and using app.use
[fixed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q68Cq.png)